# scrollspy, tooltip not working in express app

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I'm working on my express app for the first time and a lot of strange thing is happening to me. I'm trying to use scrollspy and tooltip bootstrap features but for some reason they are not working. I'm getting 2 error messages:

```
jquery.js:3841 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).scrollspy is not a function TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollspy is not a function
```

same goes for tooltip.

I would like to show you my setup here so you can comment.

I'm using handlebars and in my main.hbs I have this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    {{> _msg}}

    {{{body}}}

    <script src="/dist/vendor.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/dist/main.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using webpack and configuration is like this

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

    module.exports = {
      mode:"development",
      entry:{
        main:'./src/scripts/script.js',
        vendor:'./src/scripts/vendor.js'
      },
      output: {
        path:path.join(__dirname,'/public/dist'),
        filename:'[name].bundle.js'
      },
      devtool:'source-map',
      module:{
        rules:[
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name:"../images/[name].[ext]"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test:/\.hbs$/,
            use:'handlebars-loader'
          },
          {
            test:/\.scss$/,
            use:[
               MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
               {
                 loader:'css-loader',
                 options:{sourceMap:true}
               },
              {
                loader:'sass-loader',
                options:{sourceMap:true}
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test:/\.js$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            use:[
              {
                loader:'babel-loader',
                options:{
                  presets:['@babel/env'],
                  plugins:['transform-class-properties']
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins:[
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename:'../css/[name].css'
        })
      ]
    }
```

in my src/scripts/vendor.js I have only this

```
import "bootstrap"
```

and in my src/scripts/script.js I have all the jquery and js I would like to use accorss the pages

```
require('../scss/style.scss')
let helper = require('./functions')
const $ = require('jquery')

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#sideMenu'})

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
    {
    placement:"bottom",
    delay: {show: 100, hide: 100},
    boundary: 'window'
    }
  );
});
```

then I have page called details.hbs where I have div with id=sideMenu but when I go to this page scrollspy is not working and I'm getting error that I described before.

Same goes for the page results.hbs where I would like to show some tooltip on hover over the icon

```
<img src="/images/detail.svg" title="some title." class="tooltipImg mr-2" data-toggle="tooltip">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was just missing bootstrap.bundle.min.js. I was confused because I had

`import "bootstrap"` in  src/scripts/vendor.js file and I thought that this will also import bundle.js